# CLIPS Error：Template xxx does not exist for assert

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clips, expert-system

- CLIPS version: `6.31`
- language: `c++` `clips C API`

Why am I getting this error? How should I fix this error?

```
[FACTRHS1] Template be-contact-model.riskLevel does not exist for assert.
Function load-facts encountered an error
```

The process is as follows: Firstly, I create a CLIPS environment from the full clips rule code using the `ClipsEnvLoadFromString` function, I will get a normal result in this CLIPS environment using the `EnvLoadFactsFromString` function.Next I want to copy more than one CLIPS environment,
so I save the rules in a binary image file using the `EnvBsave` function and then I load a new environment from a binary file using `EnvBload` function, and then I use the `EnvLoadFactsFromString` function to load the user facts.But the `EnvLoadFactsFromString` function return false, and the `cli stdout` get the error string:

```
[FACTRHS1] Template be-contact-model.riskLevel does not exist for assert.
Function load-facts encountered an error
```

The facts parameter of the `EnvLoadFactsFromString` function as following:

```
(appId "TEST")
(be-contact-model.riskLevel "PASS")
(be-contact-model.score 0)
(channel "POST_TEXT.RlokQwRlVjUrTUlkIqOg.COMMENT")
(constantKey "constantKey")
(contact.model "contact_detector(GO)")
(contact.nicknameResult.has_contact FALSE)
(contact.nicknameResult.has_qq FALSE)
(contact.nicknameResult.has_tel FALSE)
(contact.nicknameResult.has_url FALSE)
(contact.nicknameResult.has_wechat FALSE)
(contact.riskLevel "PASS")
(contact.score 0)
(contact.textResult.baidusearch.REJECT_LEVEL 0)
(contact.textResult.has_contact FALSE)
(contact.textResult.has_qq FALSE)
(contact.textResult.has_tel FALSE)
(contact.textResult.has_url FALSE)
(contact.textResult.has_wechat FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you load a binary image, you can't create any new constructs. Ordered facts and patterns (those that don't have a corresponding deftemplate construct) automatically create a deftemplate. If your rules haven't already created this automatic deftemplate, it can't be created after you've already loaded a binary image:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (bsave example.bin)
TRUE
CLIPS> (bload example.bin)
TRUE
CLIPS> (assert (be-contact-model.riskLevel "PASS"))
[FACTRHS1] Template be-contact-model.riskLevel does not exist for assert.
CLIPS>
```

If you have a rule that matches the ordered fact, you can assert this type of fact after you've loaded the binary image.

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(defrule r1
   (be-contact-model.riskLevel ?)
   =>)
CLIPS> (bsave example.bin)
TRUE
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (bload example.bin)
TRUE
CLIPS> (assert (be-contact-model.riskLevel "PASS"))
<Fact-0>
CLIPS>
```

So the fact that you're getting an error message would indicate that you're attempting to assert a fact that none of your rules can match.

It looks like your facts are attribute/value pairs, so one thing you can do if you're asserting facts that no rule can match is to create a generic deftemplate for representing all of them:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (deftemplate av (slot a) (slot v))
CLIPS> (assert (av (a be-contact-model.riskLevel) (v "PASS")))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Is there any other way?If I use a generic deftemplate, many existing conditions of rules will need to be changed, such as `(defrule r1 (be-contact-model.riskLevel "PASS")  =>)` will be `(defrule r1 (av (a be-contact-model.riskLevel) (v "PASS")  =>)`.There are too many such rules and I don't know the fact list before I get the real fact list.

Comment: The purpose of my use of the bsave function is to quickly create multiple clips environments.

Comment: There is no other way. Once you load a binary image you can't create any new constructs so you can't assert any ordered facts belonging to deftemplates that aren't already contained in the binary image.

Comment: Ok, why are there such restrictions? Can you consider providing a way to break this limit later?

Comment: The binary image is loaded and unloaded by allocating and deallocating large arrays of memory. It's not worth the effort to allow constructs to be incrementally added to a binary image for this one scenario. I don't recommend using ordered facts other than in limited circumstances. They were originally the only means of representing facts before deftemplates were introduced, so they are still available to be used, but explicitly defining deftemplates is the recommended method for representing facts.

Comment: One other alternative that involves less change to the patterns is to keep the ordered facts but prefix all the patterns with av: (defrule r1 (av be-contact-model.riskLevel "PASS") =>).

Comment: Good idea! This can really make minor changes.Thanks~